# Zero normalize a vector field

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a vector field that I would like to normalize, e.g.

```
v1 = (1,1)
v2 = (1,2)
v3 = (1,3)
v4 = (1,4)
```

where their norms are

```
1,414   
2,236
3,162
4,123
```

and I intend to normalize them into the range [0,1].

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling

I already used this in each component of the vectors, and it isn't working!

```
a = [1 1;1 1]; b = [1 2; 3 4]; % x & y components
v = zeros(2,2,2);
v(:,:,1) = a;
v(:,:,2) = b; % 2x2x2 matrix
vn = sqrt(v(:,:,1).^2+v(:,:,2).^2); % norm of the 4 vectors
vnmin = min(min(vn)); % minimum length
vnmax = max(max(vn)); % maximum length
v = v-vnmin;
v = v/(vnmax-vnmin); % apply feature scaling
```

Regards :)

Comment: Can you send use the code of what you have already tried?

Comment: The vectors are in the third dimension of the array
`a = [1 1;1 1];

b = [1 2; 3 4];

v = zeros(2,2,2);

v(:,:,1) = a;

v(:,:,2) = b;

vn = sqrt(v(:,:,1).^2+v(:,:,2).^2);

vnmin = min(min(vn));

vnmax = max(max(vn));

v = v-vnmin;

v = v/(vnmax-vnmin);`

Comment: Please edit the code into your question (nicely formatted ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that you are not using the rigth values when scaling, you should do

```
vn = vn-vnmin;
vn = vn/(vnmax-vnmin); % applying feature scaling
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm computing the norms, then normalizes ALL vectors to unit length, and after that, multiplying everyone for it's 'scaling' given by the matrix up there!